# Excel: Sum value of B but not if A contains specific text

Tags: excel, formula

I need to Sum the values in a table of duplicates, but NOT sum if text “Special” is present. For Special I want it to return a sum of “0” or even N/A.

As per the template sample, consolidate A:B to C:D but do not sum "Special". Return a "0" or N/A.

[template sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8r5l.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is in A1, I suggest in D2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(C2="Special",0,SUMIF(A:A,C2,B:B))
```

This first tests for `Special` and returns `0` if in the same row of the `C` column and where not `Special` there applies a standard [=SUMIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php).

Change the `0` to `"NA"` if that is what you prefer for `Special`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, WORKED PERFECT!